# Why is code colouring and code sense not working for me in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I use Xcode 4.6.2 on a 13″ MacBook Air. At the beginning there was code sense and code coloring, but all of a sudden the code colors disappeared, there is no code completion (there is – only for words I have already typed in the current file), so for example if I have a class header, the methods and variables are not auto-completed in the implementation file (.m).

I've googled around everywhere, and checked a lot of questions on Stack Overflow, but to no avail. I've tried restarting Xcode or clearing the derived data, which didn't help.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

This situation is very frustrating, and I can no longer work in Xcode until I resolve this situation.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all those suspicious-looking upside-down question marks?

Comment: wow, I actually tried deleting them and the code completion returned to life! thanks for the quick diagnosis...

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the upside-down question marks.  The code coloring seems to stop working at the first of them.